# How to auto login in Odoo's Web-module for res.user, not for res.partner?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-10, odoo-11, odoo-12

I am trying to login using token-based Auth, because we are using Odoo-web module in mobile-app.

currently using GET-method url-passing approach which is "UNSECURE" on websites without SSL certificates and localhost-websites, as

`myurl.com?username=foo&password=bar`

How can I do that using Token based approach or passing credentials in POST-method, in Odoo-12?

**Edit 1:**

I found this authenticate() method in core-modules of odoo in http-controllers file and I am calling that only now, as:

`request.session(db, username, password)`

but I wanted it to be token based without hardcoding password as different passwords for different partners, which I can't hardcode and it's bad approach.

how can I do it by passing token and validating it?

Comment: look at "survey" module, it uses something like you want (auth based on token)

Comment: @m0r7y, Thanks. but auth based token works for "frontend" or for all users, I wanted to load "web-backend" module where all settings and configurations are accessed.

Comment: I found similar question asked on odoo-forums as here: https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/alternative-ways-of-login-to-odoo-web-backend-ui-155805

Comment: I posted it on Github-issues:  https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues/45915

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `authenticate` endpoint provided by odoo to create a session for your api user.
In the following requests you then use the `session id` to process operations.

Example call to /web/session/authenticate with body:

```
{
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "method": "call",
  "id": 1,
  "params": {
    "db": "<YOUR-DB>",
    "login": "<YOUR@LOGIN.COM>",
    "password": "<YOUR-PASSWORD>"
  }
}
```

You can find a description of the endpoints in https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/12.0/odoo/http.py

Comment: thanks @grafgustav, but I found this authenticate() method in core-modules of odoo in http-controllers file and I am calling that only now. but I wanted it to be token based without hardcoding password as different passwords for different partners, which I can't hardcode.

Comment: I want to use Web-backend for for POS Users.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know about any way to do this without using credentials. Apparently it is not natively supported, as [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58928416/api-authenticate-to-odoo-with-token) suggests. 
The referenced PR [link](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/pull/33928) just recently passed all checks, so maybe it will be a feature of the next version.